# Measuring the running time and query answering time of GUI Jar file in Linux

Tags: command-line, java, gui, jar

I have a GUI jar file (taken from [here](http://www.modeus.uniroma1.it/modeus/node/6)). I need to measure the shell time of loading a file in this jar and then query-answering time of this jar. The problem is the code is not provided with this jar. So, i cannot inject anything in it. I need to use this as it is. If i use `time` command with this jar file it gives me overall time of the whole gui and interaction. All i want the above mentioned two times. I don't know how to achieve this in Linux (as i am new to linux commands) using 3rd-party jar file. Anyhelp would be appreciated.